# Find values that increment or decrement by 1 in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find a way to find strings that are like '1234', '12345', '9876', '7654', etc. So values that have numbers that are sequential either up or down. Anywhere from 3 characters (ex. 123, 321) to 10 characters (0123456789, 9876543210)

```
INSERT INTO #TmpTbl 
Values ('12345')
,('45678')
,('44569')
,('987654')
,('748376')
,('123')
,('0123456789')
,('9876543210')
```

Expected Results

- 12345
- 45678
- 987654
- 123
- 0123456789
- 9876543210

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `LIKE` to find the patterns. For example:

```
select * 
from t
where '0123456789' like concat('%', a, '%')
   or '9876543210' like concat('%', a, '%');
```

Result:

```
a
----------
12345
45678
987654
123
0123456789
9876543210
```

See example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a8080a4af4b5e17ae99f77d1641b18e5).

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe it was that easy... I'll accept the answer when it allows me to.